# How to Detect Video Recording Time Programmatically

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I have set `mEdiaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60 * 1000);` (60 seconds) in my video recording app and I want to trigger a method when the time is expired of recording. Help me finding a way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new medialistener());

class medialistener implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener {     
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder recorder, int what, int extra)
    { 
        if(what==MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED)
        {
                // Do what you want to do...
        }

     // Log.i("video test", "Video Info: "+what+", "+extra);  
     } 
}
```